# Detecting user copying with NPAPI & Firebreath

Tags: npapi, firebreath

I have developed a simple `NPAPI plugin` using `Firebreath` - the `plugin` is used to launch another process when a particular `URL` is visited.

I would like to extend the plugin to detect and log what users (on an intranet) are copying from and optionally restrict which users can copy content based on their role.

I have not been able to understand how I could detect the copy event (if such a thing exists) - any help and direction would be appreciated.  I'm specifically looking at `Chrome` on Windows initially.

Many thanks,

Jon

Comment: What copying are you referring to?

Comment: I'm interested in logging what text a user may copy from the webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of what you're describing can be done with a NPAPI plugin.  NPAPI plugins don't know anything about browsers copying and pasting, nor do they know anything about what URLs the browser visits, unless they happen to exist as an object tag on the page.

At best, what you're trying to do would require an extension, though I don't know if it's possible or not.

See http://npapi.com/extensions

Comment: thank you for clarifying just what a plugin can and cannot do - I was thinking of them as being analogous to IE's BHOs.  Given that I'm going to deploying into a very controlled environment I suspect I should be able to use a javascript technique to catch key-presses such as ctrl-c and then log the event via a web service.